# Align text in table html

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have table:

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="50%">Name</th>
      <th width="50%"><span style="width: 50%;text-align: left;">Price</span> / <span style="width: 50%;text-align: right;">Einheit</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name1</td>
      <td><span style="width: 50%;text-align: left;">1000</span> / <span style="width: 50%;text-align: right;">Hour</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name2</td>
      <td><span style="width: 50%;text-align: left;">250.50</span> / <span style="width: 50%;text-align: right;">Day</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Need that 1000 and 250.50  were  under the word Price, Hour and Day were under the word Einheit. I tried do it using width property and text-align but it doesnt work.

Need this result, for example:
https://clip2net.com/s/3ZXsphT

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By Default `span` tag is inline element, it doesn't take width. You need to change `span` tag to block label element using `display` or `float`. check updated snippet below...

```css
td span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 47%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th width="50%">Name</th>
    <th width="50%"><span style="width: 50%;text-align: left;">Price</span> / <span style="width: 50%;text-align: right;">Einheit</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Name1</td>
    <td><span style="text-align: right;">1000</span> / <span style="text-align: left;">Hour</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name2</td>
    <td><span style="text-align: right;">250.50</span> / <span style="text-align: left;">Day</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS

```css
table tr td:nth-child(even){
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="50%">Name</th>
      <th width="50%"><span>Price</span> / <span>Einheit</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name1</td>
      <td><span>1000</span> / <span>Hour</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name2</td>
      <td><span>250.50</span> / <span>Day</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Seems a nice and clean solution to me. Though the 4th, 6th, etc, columns will be centered as well. To only center the second column, use `table tr td:nth-child(2){
text-align:center;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need any single span as none was executed.

price / Einheit was centered only as this is the default of th tag

So, in order to align the cell beneath it, you can just code **td style=" text-align:center"**

and if you want to align all cells to the center

**table style="text-align:center"**